# How can I detect a click on ellipsis (...) in browser?

Tags: javascript, css

It seems to be hopeless, because the ellipsis is not in the DOM, it's just a render trick by the browser

I am asking because I am not a html/css guru, so many ezoteric tricks may exist I am not aware...

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will be a little tricky...It looks like you are using `.ellipsis` class on ellipsis text...

...so try to append a `span` on every `.ellipsis` class element using `each` jQuery. Use `position` to align that `span` at end of text

...and then add a click event to that `span`

*<sup>**Note:** I added a background color to that `span` just for visual</sup>*

***Stack Snippet***

```js
$(".ellipsis").each(function() {
  $(this).append("<span class='dots'></span>")
})

$(document).on("click", ".dots", function() {
  console.log("ellipsis element is clicked");
})
```

```css
p {
  width: 150px;
  border: 1px solid;
  font: 13px Verdana;
}

.ellipsis {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: relative;
}

span.dots {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 12px;
  background: #ff000052;
  z-index: 99;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="ellipsis">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
<p class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
<p class="ellipsis">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
<p class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
```

Comment: @mdawsondev yeah I got it wrong earlier...Updated..!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot attach events to pseudo-content, and text overflow characters are pseudo-content, in the same way content rendered by `::before` and `::after` is pseudo-content.

And like all pseudo-content, any clicks to it will trigger an event on the element to which it belongs.

Comment: To literally detect clicks on the ellipsis? Only to handle overflow/ellipsis yourself. The ellipsis will need to be in an element e.g. `span`.

Answer (score -3):

Maybe add an event listener to the window and check if the mouse click has the same x and y coordinates as your ellipses?